# Effects of publishing DNSSEC DS records without signing public zone?

Tags: bind, dnssec

We at `example.com` are being pressured to implement DNSSEC by a sub-division of our organisation: `security.example.com`.

Our current name servers `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com` are unsigned, non-dnssec servers.

We would like to use `ns1.example.com` as a hidden master and implement **inline signing** in bind as per: [Example #2](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00626/0/Inline-Signing-in-ISC-BIND-9.9.0-Examples.html) . Our new DNSSEC enabled servers for `example.com` will be `dns1.example.com` and `dns2.example.com`.

We would like to publish the `DS` records to the `.com` registrar so that we can internally test the new DNSSEC servers. The `SOA` would remain `ns1.example.com` (And the `NS` records would not include the DNSSEC servers for the time being).

**My question is:**

If we publish `DS` records to `.com` for our DNSSEC servers, will dnssec-validating DNS servers break when they realize there is no DNSSEC functionality at `ns1.example.com` or `ns2.example.com`?

**AND**

Are there any other side effects we should be on the lookout for with this hybrid setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you publish DS records in the tld zone and your public nameservers do not support DNSSEC then your records will fail validation.